# What is the Mistake in the line integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to find the line integral of $x dy$  where the curve is $x^2 +y^2 =a^2$
I know that if I take $x=(a^2-y^2)^\frac(1/2)$ for the semicircle right of $x=0$ ie $x$ ranges from $-a$ to $a$ (keeping in the mind the anticlockwise rotation) and $x = -(a^2 -y^2)^{\frac12}$ for $x$ ranging from $a$ to $-a$ and carry out the integration I get $\pi a^2$.

But if I do this way
$$
2x dx + 2y dy = 0\quad\text{so}\quad dy = -\frac{x}{y} dx
$$
but $y = (a^2-x^2)^(1/2)$ and replacing this for $dy$ in the Integral and keeping rotation anticlockwise I need to find the Integral of  $-\frac{x^2}{(a^2- x^2)^(1/2)}$ from $a$ to $-a$, the  answer to which comes $-\frac{\pi a^2}{2}$ .

And $y = -((a^2-x^2)^{1/2}$ and replacing this for $dy$ in the Integral and keeping rotation anticlockwise I need to find the Integral of $\frac{x^2}{(a^2- x^2)^{1/2}}$ from $-a$ to $a$, the  answer to which comes -$\frac{\pi a^2}{2}$

So the total is $-\pi a^2$

Why is the answer coming $-\pi a^2$ this way when the sense of rotation is not changed. What's the fault ?

Comment: Try learning and using MathJax next time you ask a question, to make it more readable: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Observe that $\;x^2+y^2=a^2\implies y=\pm\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\;$ , and for some reason you seem to have ommited the square root in the denominator in the second method. In the answer below I give you another method, the one which, imo, is the easiest one in this case.

Comment: Your method is right but what is wrong I'm method. Why is the answer coming -πa^2 ? I had taken the square root. I have corrected it. But what the fault in my method. The answer should have been πa^2 but why is it coming -πa^2 ?

Comment: @user379001 You seem to have done$$\int_{-a}^a\frac{-x^2dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=-2\int_0^a\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$
 But the above is wrong: going from $\;-a\;$ to $\;a\;$ *on the upper hemisphere* gives you **negative direction** ! The limits must be changed from $\;a\;$ to $\;-a\;$ in the upper hemisphere, and something similar (with changed limits, of course) in thelower hemisphere. That's how you get the correct number with the wrong sign.

Answer (score 1):

Another method which imo is easier than yours, after I commented below your question:

Why not to use the usual, standard parametrization of that circle?:

$$\begin{cases}x=a\cos t\\{}\\y=a\sin t\end{cases}\;\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi\implies dy=a\cos t\,dt$$

and thus the integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}a\cos t\cdot a\cos t\,dt=a^2\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2t\,dt=\left.\frac{a^2}2\left(t+\cos t\sin t\right)\right|_0^{2\pi}=$$

$$=\frac{a^2}2(2\pi)=a^2\pi$$

Comment: Your method is right but what is wrong I'm method. Why is the answer coming -πa^2 ? I had taken the square root. I have corrected it. But what the fault in my method. The answer should have been πa^2 but why is it coming -πa^2 ?

Comment: @user379001 Read my comment below your question.

Comment: No for the upper semicircle I have taken y as the positive root and integrated from a to -a ( anticlockwise) and for the lower semicircle , I have taken y as the negative root and integrated from -a to a (anticlockwise ) and that's how I got -πa^2 instead of πa^2 . I have taken different values of  y ( the root) , ie. Positive and negative and maintained the anticlockwise rotation but still got -πa^2. Actually if you see the '-' in dy =(-x/y * dx ) is causing the problem but that '-' is but necessary !

Comment: @user379001 Then you made a mistake in signs somewhere (I can't know and how: you didn't show your actual integration) : I did it your way and it came out correct.

Comment: Since I am new to math jax , I can't provide the complete integration but pls check the answer

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28-+x%5E2+%2F%28%28+a%5E2-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29&x=0&y=0

Comment: @user379001 I won't even begin to check that and even less to substitute the limits. Check what I did with what I think is a simple substitution.Observe I **don't put the minus sign**:  $$\int_{-a}^a\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=2\int_0^a\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$
now substitute:
$$x=a\sin u\implies dx=a\cos udu\implies2\int_0^a\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{a^2\sin^2u}{a\cos u}\cdot a\cos udu=$$
$$\left.2\int_0^{\pi/2}a^2\sin^2u\,du=a^2(u-\cos u\sin u)\right|_0^{\pi/2}=a^2\frac\pi2=a^2\pi$$and I can't see how you did integrate that to get a negative result

Comment: When y is positive and for the limits a to -a it gives -πa^2/2.    For negative y the solution will be. http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28x%5E2+%2F%28%28+a%5E2-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29&x=0&y=0.  And the limits -a to a give -πa^2/2. The total is hence -πa^2

Comment: @user379001 Sorry, it is not so and the above (both my answer and my comment) proves it, so either at least you or I are mistaken, or a mathematical miracle has occurred... DId you check what I did above?

Comment: Yah , I checked what you did and saw you haven't put the negative sign. But then how can Wolfram Alpha give a wrong result

Comment: BTW, in what you sent from Wolfram, observe that (and take into consideration that $$\;\arctan\frac x{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\xrightarrow[x\to a^\pm]{}\pm\frac\pi2\; )\;:$$ $$\frac12\left(x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-a^2\arctan\frac x{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)_{-a}^a=$$
$$\frac12\left(\left[a\cdot\sqrt0-a^2\frac\pi2\right]-\left[(-a)\cdot\sqrt0-a^2\left(-\frac\pi2\right)\right]\right)=\frac12\left(-\frac{a^2\pi }2-\frac{a^2\pi}2\right)=-\frac{a^2\pi}2$$
**iff**   you go fron left to right (i.e., in the *negative direction*) . If you do from $\;a\;$ (lower limit!) to (-a) (upper limit), you get the correct quantity

Comment: @First, WA doesn't give this time a wrong result: look above to my past comment. Second, WA gives wrong or partial results **many times**, in particular in confusing cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems I was wrong input which   messed the signs